# Reference request: (spectral) convergence rate of sample covariance matrix with fixed dimension $p$

Tags: mathematical-statistics, covariance-matrix, spectral-analysis, random-matrix

I am looking for a reference on convergence of sample covariance matrix (in some reasonable sense) when the dimension **$p$ is fixed**, but the number of samples $n$ goes to infinity. The ideal result I am looking for is a convergence rate in terms of the empirical spectral distribution $$F(x)=\frac1p\sum_{i=1}^p 1_{\lambda_i\leq x}$$
where $\lambda_i,\cdots,\lambda_p$ are the eigenvalues of the sample covariance matrix (say $S_n$). Such result seems to be known when $p/n$ converges to a number in $(0,1)$, for instance in https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aos/1384871346 or some of the earlier works. But curiously I can only seem to find a.s. convergence without the rate, to something called the semicircle law (e.g. https://www.jstor.org/stable/2243844?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents).

I am overall confused that I can't find anything on the seemingly easier case of fixed $p$. Also, as I see in some lecture note [http://math.mit.edu/~liewang/ECM.pdf](http://math.mit.edu/%7Eliewang/ECM.pdf) that in this classical case the convergence rate is of order $n^{-1/2}$ (without any reference or stating which sense), I suspect that some result is widely known. Even if it's not in the spectral sense, any quantitative result would likely help me, so any input is appreciated.

I know nothing about random matrix theory and only little about statistics, so I would be grateful if the answers didn't assume too much background knowledge (but I'm okay
with math and some probability, so I'm fine with what could be understood in ~10 mins from a Wikipedia page).